# SKPaymentQueue presentCodeRedemptionSheet crashes on maccatalyst

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, mac-catalyst

[presentCodeRedemptionSheet](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue/3566726-presentcoderedemptionsheet) call crashes on maccatalyst (ran on macOS 12.3.1):

```
[SKPaymentQueue presentCodeRedemptionSheet]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

It's easy to reproduce if you create a new project and invode this method on maccatalyst. Has anyone found a solution to this?
On a side note: this API looks broken on iOS in debug mode. Only the app store build present the redeem voucher controller.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue/3566726-presentcoderedemptionsheet?changes=lat_7_8&language=objc) this API is not available for MacCatalyst apps even though it is marked as so.

> This function doesn’t affect Mac apps built with Mac Catalyst.